# How do i scale svg <image> element to fill entire <svg> area?

Tags: html, image, svg

[This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rafael_cichocki/2qexypLs/3/).

```
<svg version="1.1" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    width="400px" 
    height="400px" 
    viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" 
    preserveAspectRatio="none" 
    style="border: 1px solid black;">

    <image x="0" y="0" 
            width="1000" 
            height="1000"
            xlink:href="http://www.bized.co.uk/sites/bized/modules/bized_cb_navigation/images/floorplan_info.gif">
    </image>
</svg>
```

1. My actual drawing area is 400px x 400px.
2. I define a coordinate system on this of (0,0) to (1000,1000).
3. I set the image to `x=0 y=0 width=1000 height=1000`
4. The image should fill all the way from 0 to 1000 on x and y axis.

Except that 4. doesn't happen - you can see there is white-space left to the left and right. What am I missing?

Comment: btw. if you leave the viewBox and preserveAspectRatio attributes away entirely, then the image will scale automatically to fit while keeping image ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set

```
<image … preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
```

Just setting that value in the SVG tag is not enough

Comment: That did it, thanks. I didn't realize the aspect ratio described the tag it was in, I understood it describes it's inner content only.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `width="100%"` on the image, this should scale the image to 100% width of the svg.

Comment: That was my first thought, too.  However, the problem here is aspect ratios will be preserved, no matter what.  The best solution seems to be to set [preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) on the image tag.